# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'version' of undefined in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I am getting below error. Please help me to fix it.

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'version' of undefined
    at API.version (:5:30)
    at :11:8**

```
class API {

    private message: {
        version: string,
        success: boolean
    };
    public version() {
        this.message.version = "1.0";
        console.log(this.message);
    }
}

let apiObj = new API();
apiObj.version();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your class you have not initialized your `message` property to anything -- you are only setting the type for the property, so it will be `undefined` when you try to access it. That is why you get the error in this statement: `this.message.version = "1.0";`.

To fix this you can initialize the property with some default value:

```
class API {

    private message: {
        version: string,
        success: boolean
    } = {
        version: "",
        success: false
    };
}
```